# Save PDF that is embedded in Excel as separate file

Tags: c#, excel, comobject

Updated - I am working on retrieving data from a large number of Excel workbooks using C#. There are some important pdf documents  that are embedded in the workbooks. I need to save them as individual document for further processing.

I am able to loop through all oleObject in all worksheets and find all pdfs.

I used progID in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet to identify the pdfs 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.oleobjects?view=openxml-2.8.1

```
  foreach(Worksheet ws in xlWb.Worksheets)
        {      
            foreach (OLEObject ole in ws.OLEObjects())
            {
                  //identify whether the oleObject is of AcroExch class type
                   if(ole.progID == "AcroExch.Document.DC")
                {
                   //2. Cast oleObject to AcroExch and save it as a pdf separately 
                }


            }
        }
```

From what I gathered online, using acrobat dc sdk seems to be the only option. 
Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the `OLEObject.Creator` property can be used to indicate Acrobat PDF files. I don't know what 32-bit value is for Acrobat, specifically, however.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778729/download-embedded-pdf-file-in-excel  there is some code in this thread, perhaps that will be helpful

Comment: @Dai OLEObject.Creator does not work.  I imported DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet  and use if(ole.progID == "AcroExch.Document.DC") to identify pdf

Comment: @AllenKing thanks. I ended up using the code from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358982/how-to-download-embedded-pdf-files-in-an-excel-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

To extract embedded pdf and save to pdf, please refer to this solution provided by GemBox Dev Team:
[How to download embedded PDF files in an excel worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22452233/2699178)